# How to fill NaN of a column if the same duplicated entry exists

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, fillna

I have 2 columns in my dataframe namely LocationID and LocationName.

LocationID is not having any NAN entries. However, some of the rows have NaN entires in the LocationName Column. Each Location Name is associated with a unique LocationID.

LocationID and LocationName columns have many duplicated entries in the dataframe.

How do I fill NaN Entries of LocationName column associated with a LocationID if there exists a data point in the dataframe for the same LocationID with no NaN in the LocationName Column.

A sample looks like this:

```
LocationID  LocationName
1   Bengaluru
2   Delhi
3   Mysore
1   
1   
4   Nagpur
2   
2   Delhi
3   Mysore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Pandas function `fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) can take a Series mapping each index to the value that should be used to fill the missing value.

So we need to gather a Series mapping each unique LocationID to a LocationName:

```py
df = df.set_index("LocationID")  # in case it wasn't already the index
df = df.replace("", np.nan)  # in case your missing values are empty strings instead of actual NaNs

mapping = df["LocationName"].dropna().drop_duplicates()
print(mapping)
```

Outputs:

```
           LocationName
LocationID             
1             Bengaluru
2                 Delhi
3                Mysore
4                Nagpur
```

Now we apply this to the original dataframe using `fillna()`:

```py
df["LocationName"].fillna(mapping, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
LocationID             
1             Bengaluru
2                 Delhi
3                Mysore
1             Bengaluru
1             Bengaluru
4                Nagpur
2                 Delhi
2                 Delhi
3                Mysore
```

Optionally put back the original index, if LocationID wasn't your index already.

Answer (score 0):

Below should be able to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1 , 'Bengaluru'], [2, 'Delhi'], [1, np.nan], [3, 'Mysore'], [2, 'Delhi']], columns=['LocationID', 'LocationName']) 
look_up_df = df[df.LocationName.notnull()].drop_duplicates(['LocationID']) 
look_up_df = look_up_df.set_index('LocationID')['LocationName']
df['LocationName'] = df['LocationName'].fillna(df['LocationID'].map(look_up_df))
```

Input:

```
    LocationID  LocationName
0   1   Bengaluru
1   2   Delhi
2   1   NaN
3   3   Mysore
4   2   Delhi

Output:

    LocationID  LocationName
0   1   Bengaluru
1   2   Delhi
2   1   Bengaluru
3   3   Mysore
4   2   Delhi
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'LocationID':[1,2,3,1,1,4,2,2,3],'LocationName':['Bangalore','Delhi','Mysore',np.nan,np.nan,'Nagpur',np.nan,'Delhi','Mysore']})
df=df.set_index(df['LocationID'])
df['LocationName']=[df['LocationName'][df['LocationID']==i].dropna().drop_duplicates().values[0] for i in df['LocationID']]
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```